# Image cropping problems

Tags: css

I have a div which crops images to 600px high, this is what the code looks like:

```
 .post .cutoff {
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.post .cutoff img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

And it works fine, but if the image isn't 600px or taller, any thing underneath it will be spaced until 600px has been met. Like this:

[image]

See, there's an annoying space... How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have any living example?

Comment: Better solution is to use img as background and set background-size: cover but if you must set img as img then you can do this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/208/

Answer (score 0):

Use following property to cover image to element

```
.post .cutoff{
    background:url(image.png) center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

`background-size:cover;` will stretch image to `width` & `height` of the element. And to receive a decent effect you have to `center/align` image as i did

Also use much smaller image will look pixlated when you will enlarge to cover element

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because your function resizes the division and not the image.
You could use javascript to do this!
Please specify what is post and cutoff.Are these the class names of the division and image respectively?
If yes,then it should work fine.

Otherwise you could use this piece of javascript to get the job done.

```
  var x = document.getElementById("imageid").getAttribute("height");
    if (x<600 || x>600)
    {
     document.getElementById("imageid").setAttribute("height","600px");
    }
```

This would check if the image height is below or above 600px before increasing the height.